# CString maximum length

Tags: mfc, cstring

What is the maximum length in characters a CString object can hold?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Up to your available memory or INT_MAX-1 (whichever is less).

Comment: It should always be INT_MAX-1, because even if you only have 100megs of RAM, virtual memory will store the rest.

Comment: @Orion: only to a point. On 32-bit Windows, user-mode programs will have somewhat less than 2GB of address space available (since the program itself will take up some space).

Comment: The length is not limited only to the available memory, but to the size of the largest available continuous memory block. Which could be less than INT_MAX-1, depending on what else you have loaded in the memory and how fragmented your heap is.

Comment: He asked for the length in characters, not bytes, so the size of the character matters: `sizeof(TCHAR)` could be 1 or 2 depending on whether `UNICODE` is `#define`ed somewhere.

Comment: @Nathan Yellin - because one char is reserved for the terminating `\x0` char

Comment: @Nathan Yellin - soery, answered the wrong question. It's INT_MAX, because the variable holding the length is of type int.

Answer (score 2):

INT_MAX - 1

Answer (score 0):

[2,147,483,647](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a994dfk(VS.80).aspx) characters